Need help OBS Studio 30.2.3 on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS had no display capture feature
I had Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS and I just install OBS Studio 30.2.3 to record my meeting
I had found in OBS that there's no Display capture on the Source tab, while I had seen it on the OBS for Wind*W
If there's someone had a solution for my issue, please help me
Thank you
PS: if only there's another solution to record my meeting with other apps, it's always welcome
